# Ubuntu 16.04.5 USB wifi Adapter: 0bda:b812 not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, ndiswrapper

Just build my own computer and installed ubuntu 16.04. But I can't seem to get my wifi usb adapter working. It's an **iptimeA3000UA**. Although the packaging said it only works for windows, I thought it would be fine.

Here's my wireless info script as suggested I should add:

*$ lsusb* gives me:

```
ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I downloaded the original windows drivers and used ndiswrapper (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper). I installed it properly and it also gives "hardware present: yes", but still no wifi.

*$ ndiswrapper -L* gives me:

```
netrtwlanu : driver installed
device (0BDA:B812) present
```

So on this site I found that mine is 8812bu iguess:
https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8812BU_USB_Module:

"0bda:b812  Realtek RTL8812BU Wireless 802.11ac 2x2 USB 3.0 NIC"

So I tried to install drivers for RTL8822BU (works for 8812 too I guess) off of github https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8822bu, but still no luck.

I am doing something wrong, or does my device simply not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution:

https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_26334.20180126_COEX20171012-5044

did as instructed and works like a charm!! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me too (I tried the new repo https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959)

Comment: Latest repo from a few days ago... https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu  Using this on Linux Mint 21 and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with a Techkey-6B06, which uses an RTL8812BU chipset.

1. `git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu`
2. modify `build.sh`: It's missing `sudo` in front of each `dkms` command.
3. `chmod +x build.sh`
4. `./build.sh`

Then just configure your wifi settings in Ubuntu as normal.

If you want to have the driver available at startup, it will be convenient to register it in DKMS. An executable explanation of how to do so can be found in the script deploy.sh. Since registering a kernel module in DKMS is a major intervention, only execute it if you understand what the script does.

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu  
cd rtl88x2bu/ && ./deploy.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me on Linux MX.  If you don't have internet on the computer that is needing wifi, download the code on to a USB key and then plug it in on the other computer: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/archive/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a.zip

Comment: The answer provided by AlbertY also worked on Linux Mint 20.2 (Uma) with the Maxesla Mini WiFi Adapter 1200M 802.11ac Dual Band 2.4/5GHz AC1200 Wireless Network Adapter. The repo code has changed slightly but the steps are basically the same: 1. `git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu` 2. `cd rtl88x2bu` 3. `sudo ./deploy.sh` 4. Reboot machine

Answer (score 0):

Eyal's answer worked on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with kernel 4.15. I bought the Techkey Wireless USB WiFi Adapter, 1200Mbps Dual Band 2.42GHz/300Mbps 5.8GHz/867Mbps High Gain Dual 5dBi Antennas Network WiFi USB 3.0 for Desktop Laptop with Windows 10/8/7/XP, Mac OS/10.4-10.15.

Steps are as follows:

1. Download  https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/archive/5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a.zip
2. `cd path/to/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1_30362.20181109_COEX20180928-6a6a`
3. `sudo chmod +x build.sh`
4. `bash build.sh`