# USB wifi adapter installation with error

Tags: wireless, usb, compiling, adapter

I tried to follow a tutorial of installing the same USB wifi adapter on [Github](https://github.com/MingxuZhang/rtl8821cu). However it doesn't work. Here are the error log:

```
user@user-desktop:~/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master$ make
make CFLAGS_FLOAT="-mhard-float -mfloat-abi=hard" V=1 ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-25-generic/build M=/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
Makefile:970: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/8821cu.ko;) > /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/modules.order
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/.rtw_cmd.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-int-in-bool-context -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -mrecord-mcount -O1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -Wno-date-time -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/hal/phydm -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/platform -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/hal/btc -DCONFIG_RTL8821C -DCONFIG_MP_VHT_HW_TX_MODE -DCONFIG_MP_INCLUDED -DCONFIG_EFUSE_CONFIG_FILE -DEFUSE_MAP_PATH=\"/system/etc/wifi/wifi_efuse_8821cu.map\" -DWIFIMAC_PATH=\"/data/wifimac.txt\" -DCONFIG_TRAFFIC_PROTECT -DCONFIG_LOAD_PHY_PARA_FROM_FILE -DREALTEK_CONFIG_PATH=\"\" -DCONFIG_TXPWR_BY_RATE_EN=1 -DCONFIG_TXPWR_LIMIT_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_MODE=0 -DCONFIG_BR_EXT '-DCONFIG_BR_EXT_BRNAME="'br0'"' -DCONFIG_RTW_NAPI -DCONFIG_RTW_GRO -DCONFIG_MP_VHT_HW_TX_MODE -mhard-float -DCONFIG_RTW_DEBUG -DRTW_LOG_LEVEL=4 -DDM_ODM_SUPPORT_TYPE=0x04 -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DCONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211 -DRTW_USE_CFG80211_STA_EVENT  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"rtw_cmd"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"8821cu"' -c -o /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.c
In file included from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:302:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:303:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:323: recipe for target '/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
Makefile:1908: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
user@user-desktop:~/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 048d:1366 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 17ef:602d Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@user-desktop:~/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master$ ls
clean  hal          include  Makefile       os_dep    README.md    runwpa
core   ifcfg-wlan0  Kconfig  modules.order  platform  rtl8821c.mk  wlan0dhcp
user@user-desktop:~/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master$ make
make CFLAGS_FLOAT="-mhard-float -mfloat-abi=hard" V=1 ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-25-generic/build M=/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
Makefile:970: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/8821cu.ko;) > /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/modules.order
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/.rtw_cmd.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-int-in-bool-context -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -mrecord-mcount -O1 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused -Wno-date-time -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/hal/phydm -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/platform -I/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/hal/btc -DCONFIG_RTL8821C -DCONFIG_MP_VHT_HW_TX_MODE -DCONFIG_MP_INCLUDED -DCONFIG_EFUSE_CONFIG_FILE -DEFUSE_MAP_PATH=\"/system/etc/wifi/wifi_efuse_8821cu.map\" -DWIFIMAC_PATH=\"/data/wifimac.txt\" -DCONFIG_TRAFFIC_PROTECT -DCONFIG_LOAD_PHY_PARA_FROM_FILE -DREALTEK_CONFIG_PATH=\"\" -DCONFIG_TXPWR_BY_RATE_EN=1 -DCONFIG_TXPWR_LIMIT_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_EN=0 -DCONFIG_RTW_ADAPTIVITY_MODE=0 -DCONFIG_BR_EXT '-DCONFIG_BR_EXT_BRNAME="'br0'"' -DCONFIG_RTW_NAPI -DCONFIG_RTW_GRO -DCONFIG_MP_VHT_HW_TX_MODE -mhard-float -DCONFIG_RTW_DEBUG -DRTW_LOG_LEVEL=4 -DDM_ODM_SUPPORT_TYPE=0x04 -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DCONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211 -DRTW_USE_CFG80211_STA_EVENT  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"rtw_cmd"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"8821cu"' -c -o /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.c
In file included from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:302:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:303:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:323: recipe for target '/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Documents/rtl8821cu-master/rtl8821cu-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic'
Makefile:1908: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Anything went wrong?

PS: I can't use cable to connect to internet as this is institutial network, also my PC is dual boot, windows works fine with the adapter.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082824/ubuntu-16-04-5-usb-wifi-adapter-0bdab812-not-working

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt install build-essential` first?

Comment: yes....................

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for the reply, it works! Please post your answer below so I can mark as solved. Thanks again.